# Clever phase space parametrization of $n$-body processes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, phase-space

Consider the process $X\to A_1 A_2 A_3$ where $X$ in the frame where $X$ is at rest with mass $m$. It is well known from [Dalitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalitz_plot) that we may choose a frame to evaluate the Lorentz invariant phase space integrals wherein the relative angle between $A_1$ and $A_2$, $\theta_{12}$, is the only angular degree of freedom in the integrand.

This is useful because it allows us to integrate over the delta function and eliminate the angular dependence in favor of the phase space variables $m_{ij}^2 = (p_i +p_j)^2$, and in turn express the decay rate in terms of these new variables as

$$
\Gamma=\frac{1}{256 \pi^{3} m^{3}} \int d m_{1 2}^{2}\int_{m^{min}_{23}(m_{12})}^{m^{max}_{23}(m_{12})}  d m_{2 3}^{2} |\mathcal{A}|^{2} .
$$

---

However if we have, say, the 5-body process $X\to A_1 A_2 A_3 A_4 A_5$ and perform the same change of variables $m_{ij}^2 = (p_i + p_j)^2$, then integrating over the delta function will eliminate $\theta_{34}$ (or any other $\theta_{ij}$).

However, in this case the integrand will still contain the other $\cos\theta_{ij}$s, and I cant think of a frame or a parametrization of phase space that will eliminate all angular dependence in the final answer.

---

**Question**: So my question is simply if there is a clever way to handle the phase space of $n>3$ body final states that is similar to the way we handle the 3-body case?

The only thing i was able to find was is [this](https://iopscience.iop.org/0954-3899/33/1/001/media/kinematics.pdf), in which he states

> Combine some of the particles into "effective particles" and treating the final states of 2 or 3 "effective particle states:" $$ m^2_{ijk...} = (p_i + p_j + p_k + \cdots)^2 $$

but i'm not really sure what this means or how i would go about implementing this.